# Textbox2 value in the same row as current code

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to type an employee number (M-number) in Textbox2. That Employee number should be written in column H, in the same row as the code below.

After many attempts, I've only been able to insert the textbox2 value in the next available row, but not the same row.

Any help is grealy appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Const sName As String = "LS - Huawei"
Const sFirst As String = "A6"
Const sColsList As String = "B,C,D,E,F,H,J"

Const dName As String = "Personalesalg"
Const dFirst As String = "A6"

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim Criteria As String: Criteria = Textbox1.Value

' Create a reference to the Source Lookup (Column) Range.
Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
Dim slCell As Range
Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1) _
    .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
If slCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Tom kolonne i source"
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
Debug.Print "Source Lookup Range:          " & slrg.Address

' Create a reference to the Source (Entire) Row Range.
Dim rIndex As Variant: rIndex = Application.Match(Criteria, slrg, 0)
If IsError(rIndex) Then
    MsgBox "ID kan ikke findes"
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.Cells(rIndex).EntireRow
Debug.Print "Source (Entire) Row Range:    " & srrg.Address

' Create a reference to the Source (Entire) Columns Range.
Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(sCols)
Dim scrg As Range
Dim n As Long
For n = 0 To UBound(sCols)
    If scrg Is Nothing Then
        Set scrg = sws.Columns(sCols(n))
    Else
        Set scrg = Union(scrg, sws.Columns(sCols(n)))
    End If
Next n
Debug.Print "Source (Entire) Column Range: " & scrg.Address

' Create a reference to the Source (Row) Range.
Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(srrg, scrg)
Debug.Print "Source Row Range:             " & srg.Address

' Define the Destination Array.
Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Cells.Count
Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To 1, 1 To cCount)

' Write the values from the Source (Row) Range to the Destination Array.
Dim sCell As Range
Dim c As Long
For Each sCell In srg.Cells
    c = c + 1
    dData(1, c) = sCell.Value
Next sCell

' Create a reference to the Destination First Cell Range.
Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
Dim difCell As Range: Set difCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
Dim dCell As Range
Set dCell = difCell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - difCell.Row + 1) _
    .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
Dim dfCell As Range
If dCell Is Nothing Then
    Set dfCell = difCell
Else
    Set dfCell = dCell.Offset(1)
End If

' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(, cCount)
Debug.Print "Destination Range:            " & drg.Address

' Write the values from the Destination Array to the Destination Range.
drg.Value = dData

' Delete the entire row i.e. Source (Entire) Row Range.
srrg.Delete

MsgBox "Done."
Unload UserForm2
```

Comment: Why so much code? What does "the same row as the code below" mean? If you can single out the relevant bit that would help.

Comment: The code pastes the data in the next available row in Personalesalg. I would like the data from textbox2 to be pasted in the same row as the data being pulled from "LS - Huawei". If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code for what it needs to do - I would simplify and skip the whole "copy as array" part.  Sure it's a little faster but you're not going to notice the difference and you just get a ton more code to maintain...

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Const sName As String = "LS - Huawei"
    Const sFirst As String = "A6"
    Const sColsList As String = "B,C,D,E,F,H,J" '<<edited here
    
    Const dName As String = "Personalesalg"
    Const dFirst As String = "A6"

    Dim wb As Workbook, Criteria As String, m, sws As Worksheet, sfCell As Range
    Dim slrg As Range, destCell As Range, arrCols, col
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Criteria = Textbox1.Value
    
    Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName) 'source sheet
    Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst) 'EDIT - was missing this line
    Set slrg = sws.Range(sFirst, sws.Cells(Rows.Count, sfCell.Column))
    Debug.Print "Source Lookup Range:          " & slrg.Address
    
    m = Application.Match(Criteria, slrg, 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        'get the first destination cell
        Set destCell = NextEmptyCell(wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst))
        arrCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
        With sws.Rows(m)
            For Each col In arrCols
                destCell.Value = .Columns(col).Value
                Set destCell = destCell.Offset(0, 1)
            Next col
            destCell.Value = Textbox2.Value '<< edit: populate ColH
            .Delete
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No match found for '" & Criteria & "'"
    End If
    Unload Me 'Me in a userform refers to the form itself
End Sub

'find the cell below the last populated cell in the same column as `startCell`
'  if no cell are populated then return `startCell`
Function NextEmptyCell(startCell As Range) As Range
    Dim f As Range
    With startCell.Parent
        Set f = .Range(startCell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, startCell.Column)) _
                                 .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    End With
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Set NextEmptyCell = f.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        Set NextEmptyCell = startCell
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim

Thank you for commenting - I must admit, that the code is massive. Somone on here helped me with it. I made a sort of simply code first, but I couldn't get the last bits right. His code worked, so I decided to use that.

If I were to use yours, how would i go about getting textbox2 information in column H?

It must be in the same row as the criteria.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read your post.  I can fix tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for helping me Tim! I'm getting a Runtime error 91. "Object variable or with block not set" How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: According to debug, it seems to be this line:   Set slrg = sws.Range(sFirst, sws.Cells(Rows.Count, sfCell.Column))

Comment: Sorry seems like I missed a line - added above.

Comment: HI Tim!

It doesn't seem to to search Column A for the specific ID entered in the userform. It just copies the first row, if the ID is present.